# empty div and repopulate but jquery events are firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have below divs

```
  <div  id="div1"></div>
  <div  id="div2" style="display:none"></div>
```

these divs are loaded by clicking on some links. We are loading corresponding js files in that div only. When we are moving from one div to another we are calling jquery empty to clear all div and then loading content of clicked div only.
The problem is that; everytime when I moving from one div to another, event is getting propagated those many times . I think empty div is not removing event which is attached to the element and event is getting attached again.

we tried all below options

```
event.stopPropagation()
event.stopimmediatepropagation()
```

calling `$("#div1").find("*").off()` before empty div.

but nothing worked.
**Update**

I am loading below jquery bundle inside div 1

```
<script src="/some/bundles/providerdashboardindex?v=q4efyq1D6R9Q8EsGiRLSqO4B4bO-vFJB29DcG2uVel81"></script>
```

one of the function  in js is

```
$(document).on("click", "#tblPatientSearch tbody tr",function () 
{
}
```

if I keep an off before emptying div it doesn't work

```
 $("#tblPatientSearch tbody tr").off();
$("#div1").find("*").off();
$('#div1').empty().off("*");
```

none of above code is working

Comment: Please provide more coding context. For example the part where you attach the event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

This code should remove events from all children of the div.

```
$("#div1").find("*").off();
```

If the events were added to the div, the following code should work.

```
$("#div1").off();
```

Otherwise, more context is needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for jQuery off, it requires one or more specific events.

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is being added to the document element, so you need to remove it from the same element. The following should work.

```
$(document).off("click", "#tblPatientSearch tbody tr");
```

Comment: This worked but this way i need to off so many events.how can i off all document event from particular div

Comment: In order to give you better direction, I would need to understand more about the bundle you are using; is it maintained by you or your company? Can it be modified (add a destroy method)? How do you initially invoke the bundle to add to the div, is there a specific reason event delegation is being used in the bundle instead of adding the handler to the elements?

Comment: Yes I am maintaining the bundle how can i destroy all events

Comment: If you are maintaining it, is there a reason that you went with event delegation instead of adding the events to the elements that are triggering them? If you added the event to the #tblPatientSearch tbody tr element, then when you call empty, the events will automatically be removed. With event delegation, you will need to write a destroy method that removes each event that you add, it should also remove all the elements that were added as well.

Comment: A hack approach would be to try $(document).off('click');, but that will remove ALL click events from the document. You could also try namespacing your events. $(document).on('click.mybundle', "#tblPatientSearch tbody tr", function() {}); This way you could use $(document).off('click.mybundle');